# Inconsistent SQL stored procedure output from Job

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a stored procedures that refreshes my MS SQL Server 2012 table with values from an Oracle 11g Server using a linked server. Basically what I've done is create a view of the data I want to copy from Oracle on the SQL Server using Openquery. To simulate the refreshing of data, I:

1. Truncate all rows in my SQL tables
2. Insert All rows from the Views I made using Openquery to Oracle

This task usually takes about 8 seconds to complete.

The Contents of my stored procedure are as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [JCR_DTS].[dbo].[ORACLE_ALL_PROJECTS];
TRUNCATE TABLE [JCR_DTS].[dbo].[ORACLE_PROJECTS_CC];

INSERT INTO [JCR_DTS].[dbo].[ORACLE_ALL_PROJECTS]
SELECT * 
FROM [JCR_DTS].[dbo].[vwORA_ALL_PROJECTS];

INSERT INTO [JCR_DTS].[dbo].[ORACLE_PROJECTS_CC]
SELECT * 
FROM [JCR_DTS].[dbo].[vwORA_PROJECTS_CC];
```

When I execute the stored procedure manually, it runs fine and shows the newly inserted rows on the sql tables.

But when I let the job execute the stored procedure, sometimes it only performs the Truncating of both tables and no rows are inserted. This happens about 50% of the time the jobs are executed.

Anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: Are you getting an error? I would think the most likely cause would be the connection was not obtained but that should give you an error.

Comment: Check your job history to see if you can encounter any errors down the line.

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks for the reply. I did some further monitoring on the behavior of my job, and it seems to only fail during off work hours. As I've checked on the stack trace of my job, I found out the stored procedure job fails due to time out (my speculations might be due to inactivity of either database servers, not sure though). So as a workaround, I did a new job that would repeatedly run the Insertion script for Oracle to MS SQL (up to 5 attempts) until the rows have been committed should my initial job fails. This workaround works about 90% of the time.

Comment: @Jens See my reply to HLGEM.